# Display grayscale image as 3d plot

Tags: plotting, conversion

How to build 3d plot of grayscale image where x,y - pixel coordinates, z - pixel intensity?

[image]

I tried `ListPlot3D[ImageData[image]]`, but `ImageData` gives just intensities. I suppose a possible solution would be transorming image to (x-coord, y-coord, intensity) and passing this as an agrument to `ListPlot3D`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
pic = Import @ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJs60.png"
```

`ListPlot3D` can work with an array of values too. The problem is that you have quadruplets there, RGB and alpha channel. Convert it:

```
ListPlot3D[
  Reverse @ ImageData @ RemoveAlphaChannel @ ColorConvert[pic, "Grayscale"],
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Was this working with moderate sized images (~1MB)?  I'm getting massive RAM usage and then a crash with this solution.

Comment: I will verify tomorrow morning. What version are you working with @jman?

Answer (score 5):

Another nice 3D-ish plotting command is ReliefPlot. Modelling the preprocessing after Kuba's answer, this would be:

```
pic = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJs60.png";
imdData = Reverse@ImageData@ RemoveAlphaChannel@ColorConvert[pic, "Grayscale"];
ReliefPlot[imdData]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For smaller images I like the ListPlot3D with the option InterpolationOrder -> 0. Every pixel is then a nice flat tile which you can give a color with an appropriate ColorFunction.

```
t = Table[Exp[-(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/5)] Cos[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/2], {x, -10, 10, 
0.5}, {y, -10, 10, 0.5}];

i = Image[t] // ImageAdjust

lo = -0.2; hi = 1.5; ListPlot3D[i // ImageData, InterpolationOrder -> 0,
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.2}, PlotRange -> {lo, hi}, 
ColorFunction -> (Hue[(#3 - lo)/(hi - lo)] &), 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: This results in:]